# In examples/e2e_cli sample demo, all peers are default Anchor peers? No matter how it configured?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm learning the sample demo in fabric/examples/e2e_cli sample demo.
There's a configuration of Anchor peers in the file 'configtx.yaml' as below:

```
*- &Org1
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    # of the fabric.git development environment
    Name: Org1MSP
    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: Org1MSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp
    AnchorPeers:
        # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
        # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
        # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
        - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
          Port: 7051
- &Org2
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    # of the fabric.git development environment
    Name: Org2MSP
    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: Org2MSP
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp
    AnchorPeers:
        # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
        # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
        # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
        - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
          Port: 7051*
```

And in the script/script.sh file, there's a 'updateAnchorPeers' function for change and update anchorPeers? 
While I use :

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @Org1MSPanchors.tx http://127.0.0.1:7059/protolator/decode/common.Envelope > ./Org1MSPanchors.json
```

to translate the tx file to json. It seemed that all peers are AnchorPeers in the Org1MSPanchors.json file. Is there anything wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

```
"values": {
                                        "AnchorPeers": {
                                            "mod_policy": "Admins",
                                            "value": {
                                                "anchor_peers": [
                                                    {
                                                        "host": "peer0.org1.example.com",
                                                        "port": 7051
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "host": "peer1.org1.example.com",
                                                        "port": 7051
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "MSP": {}
                                    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Hyperledger Fabric are you using? Assuming latest from master and based on values provided in [`configtx.yaml`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/examples/e2e_cli/configtx.yaml) file, e.g.:

```
    - &Org1
        Name: Org1MSP    
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051
```

Each org has exactly one anchor peer:

1. `./generateArtifacts mychannel`
2. `curl -X POST --data-binary @Org1MSPanchors.tx http://127.0.0.1:7059/protolator/decode/common.Envelope -o anchors.json`
3. `cat anchors.json |  jq ".payload.data.config_update.write_set.groups.Application.groups.Org1MSP.values"`

provides expected output:

```
{
  "AnchorPeers": {
    "mod_policy": "Admins",
    "value": {
      "anchor_peers": [
        {
          "host": "peer0.org1.example.com",
          "port": 7051
        }
      ]
    },
    "version": "0"
  },
  "MSP": {
    "mod_policy": "",
    "version": "0"
  }
}
```

which as expected indicates only one anchors peer for Org1, doing same for Org2 provides symmetric result. Therefore I'd assume that you have some local problem on your environment. Or probably `Org1MSPanchors.tx` file remained from some previous trials. I'd suggest to clean up everything and trying to generate artifacts from scratch to see whenever you can clearly reproduce it.

Comment: Thank you. After clean up and reproduce, the anchor information is corresponding with the configtx.yaml now. But when doing 'updateAnchorPeers 1' in the examples/e2e_cli/scripts/script.sh， the ‘Org1MSPanchors.tx’ file should be updated? And the anchor of Org1 should changed to peer1.org1.example.com? But I can't find anything changed. Is there anything wrong? My fabric edition is V1.0.2.

Comment: No file should not be update, this file is essentially a config update transaction which used to update channel configuration parameters, in fact it get submitted to the ordering service, distributed to the peers and then used by peer to read update of anchor peers.